# Getting an access token without a Link

Tags: plaid

Is using a Link for getting access token absolutely necessary or it can be obtained using only backend?
I'm building an application which will use only few accounts and adding a Link to the UI is inconvinient and looks like an overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Link is absolutely necessary for access to real (non-Sandbox) data. If your app is essentially just for your own personal use, which it sounds from your post like it might be, you can use an existing Link integration from the Quickstart or something and then manually copy and paste the access token rather than actually implementing Link in your app. One example set of instructions on how to do this is in the [Postman readme](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-postman#making-api-calls-with-real-data-in-production-or-development).